# Array inside arrays of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need help, I can't assign the single values of the array inside the array of the array to a variable.

```
$arr_categories = array(
    array(1,"category_1",

            01=>"product name 1", 20 . "€"=> "description 1.",
            02=>"product name 2", 25 . "€"=> "description 2.",
            03=>"product name 3", 12 . "€"=> "description 3.",
            04=>"product name 4", 33 . "€"=> "description 4.",
            05=>"product name 5", 36 . "€"=> "description 5.",
        
    ),
    array(2,"category_2",

            01=>"product name 1", 20 . "€"=> "description 1.",
            02=>"product name 2", 25 . "€"=> "description 2.",
            03=>"product name 3", 12 . "€"=> "description 3.",
            04=>"product name 4", 33 . "€"=> "description 4.",
            05=>"product name 5", 36 . "€"=> "description 5.",
    
    ), 
    array(3,"category_3",

            01=>"product name 1", 20 . "€"=> "description 1.",
            02=>"product name 2", 25 . "€"=> "description 2.",
            03=>"product name 3", 12 . "€"=> "description 3.",
            04=>"product name 4", 33 . "€"=> "description 4.",
            05=>"product name 5", 36 . "€"=> "description 5.",
      
    )
);
```

I could assign the values of the second dimension array to single variables like this:

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($arr_categories);$i++){
    $category = $arr_categorie[$i];
    $category_id = $category[0];
    $category_name = $category[1];
```

But how can I use a second loop to count and extract the single values of the products?I have tried with a second "for" loop,"foreach", but nothing was working. Does someone have suggestions? Is it possible I have to modify the sintax of my multidimensional array?

I hope you can help, thank you! :-)

Comment: You'll find your life gets easier if you learn to use `foreach`, e.g. `foreach ($arr_categories as $category)`

Comment: Your inner arrays aren't working as you expect. They each have two elements with index `1`, so the `01=>` element replaces the category name. It's usually wrong to mix indexed and associative elements in the same array like this.

Comment: Please show your desired output.  Please always express your array data using the output of `var_export()`.  I find your question to be Unclear.

Comment: @mickmackusa the professor wants to create an ecommerce, he said to create a php file named categories.php (with the list of categories represented with a bootstrap card), then category.php (which is showing the list of products of one category), my output should be the Bootstrap card that is changing name and description of the products depending on the category. With a for loop I could duplicate the list of categories, but I cannot duplicate personalize the cards of my products.

Comment: @Barmar thank you Barmar, I believe I did not really understand the sintax of the arrays. Should I use a single comma to separate the different indexes of my products?

Comment: You probably don't mean to use octals as keys either: `01`

Comment: This is not a great title.  It doesn't describe your problem at all.  Please [edit] your question so that it is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you add another level of nesting, putting all the products in their own array, rather than in the category array itself. In addition, you can make the inner arrays associative rather than hard-coding specific positions.

And your innermost array also needs better structuring. I can't understand why you would use the price as a key that returns the description. You should have separate keys for price and description.

```
$arr_categories = array(
    array('id' => 1,
          'name' => "category_1",
          'products' => array(
            array('name' => "product name 1", 'price' => "20€", 'description' => "description 1."),
            array('name' => "product name 2", 'price' => "25€", 'description' => "description 2."),
            ...
          )
    ),
    ...
);
```

Then your loop can be:

```
foreach ($arr_categories as $category) {
    $category_id = $category['id'];
    $category_name = $category['name'];
    $category_products = $category['products'];
    ...
}
```

Comment: That innermost array is also in dire need of restructuring. It has unnecessary key concatenation and also mixes numeric and associative keys.

Comment: I don't see any benefit in renaming array elements.  Just access them as needed without bloating the global space with extra variables.

Comment: @mickmackusa It depends on what the rest of the loop is doing. I usually prefer to give names rather than repeatedly using indexes. I rarely worry about bloating the variable namespace.

Comment: Well in this case, there is no readability improvement in renaming `$category['id']` as `$category_id` -- it's just pure bloat.  In other words, you spend a whole line of code to reduce the variable name by just 3 characters.  If you want redundant variable names, you can destructure the first level in the `foreach()` (but I wouldn't).

Comment: Well, in real life I might use shorter variable names. But mainly I just have an aversion to repeated use of indexes, the brackets seem "noisy" to me.

Comment: @El_Vanja Thanks, I didn't even notice that, I thought it was just one long concatenation. I've improved the structuring there.

Comment: Please don't mix `array(...)` and `[...]` in your array declaration -- pick a style.

Comment: Ugh, you caught me. I started doing that in my original answer and fixed it, but then got lazy in the edit.

Comment: Guys I don't know how to to say thank you. This is my first approch to programming, I'll try and I will tell you later if everything worked.